# Clicking link to a reference table or figure always navigates to first page of the document

Tags: cross-referencing

I have this strange issue that whenever I click on the reference link for a table or figure, I donot goto the place where figure or table is labeled, but I am always navigated to first page of the whole document. Does anyone knows what might be doing wrong.

Comment: I would guess you have the `\label` command before the `\caption` command in the figure.

Comment: In some places I have label inside the caption command and in some cases I have label after the caption command. Which is the best way to put labels for figures and tables ?

Comment: Also, I get multiple warnings of type: name{figure.5.4} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I have a whole bunch of latex files and I have no clue how to reproduce this error with a MWE.

Comment: without a MWE it is hard to help. the error you get would be expected if you deleted (or otherwise caused to be renumbered) a figure that was there on the previous run, so referenced in the table of contents but not in the doc. running latex again should make it go. If you keep getting the error something is wrong, but if you don't show, we can't tell.

Comment: @nurava Editing down the source to the minimal form which still exhibits the problem is a big part of solving the problem; sometimes the solution becomes obvious then. No need to leave that part of problem solving to volunteers, don't you think?

Comment: @Stephan: Its not that I cant solve the problem. If only I had more time this week(weekend deadlines), I would have surely tried to find a work around. But I thought lets just ask today.

Comment: @nurava We'd really like to help. It's just pretty neigh impossible without MWE.

Comment: to construct a MWE, make a copy of the file(s), and start stripping down the copy until you can reproduce the error

Comment: I am attaching here a zip file containing MWE. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36115495/MWE.zip. Now can anyone run this and tell me the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Found a page. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=crossref. But I still cant get my figure references working

Comment: @nurava If the answer added does not solve your problem, can you post an example figure or table code where the link does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem,

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{chapter-1/images/CPU-Trends-HerbSutter}
 \end{center}
 \caption{Flattening of of ILP and frequency based performance scaling of processors}
 \label{fig:cputrends}
\end{figure}
```

That is, keep `caption` and `label` inside the `figure` environment, but outside  `\begin{center} ..... \end{center}`.